# LoadUrl in PhoneGap and Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on an app for android using phonegap and unity.
I wrote a plugin for phonegap that starts a new activity from phonegap that loads the unity player. When i hit the back button in the unity activity i want to go back to the phonegap activity and load my webcontainer again, but with a different url.
Whatever i try, it still loads the URL i loaded the first time. Is there any way to fix that?
Here is the Activity:

```
public class PhonegapCallsActivity extends DroidGap {

private static Boolean backButton;

    private static String url;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            Log.d("false","ERROR");
                //load index.html when i enter first time
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");  
            return;
                }

        else{
        backButton = extras.getBoolean("backButton");
            //load #two when i come back
                Log.d("true","ERROR");
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#two");

        } 
}
```

Note that logcat is tracing true and false correctly, so my variables are set properly.
I always get the index.html loaded, never index.html#two. Is it stored somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right but you are running into an Android bug. Go star:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327

In the mean time the best way to work around this issue is to store a flag in localStorage to check if you should be loading page one or page two in the JavaScript.

Comment: ok thanks i fixed it using local storage, but it took some time. What an annoying bug

Comment: Google announced that it was fixed but no idea when it will get into a release.